# Is it vaild to use "to" with "home"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I have one query: is it valid to use "to" with "home"? Is this sentence is correct or not?

> I am going to home.

In this sentence we are using "to" with the word "home".

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally don't use *to* in such context especially if you are going to *your* home.

> I'm going home *generally* means I'm going *to* my home.

Note that if you are referring to someone else's home, the preposition is required.

> I'm going *to* your home; I'm going *to* her home..and so on.

Note that the word *home* is a bit catchy and you may come across this word taking *preposition*.

Comment: Can you please explain your last sentence? I don't understand it.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I mean we may come across the word *home* having a preposition *to* -What renovations add value **to home?** But it's just when we put *go*, it makes the *go home* as a verbial phrase. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+home

Comment: I see, thanks. The singular *home* still needs an identifier in that case, though the plural *homes* does not. Certainly you're correct that *to [...] home* is a common occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

"Home" is a noun as in "My home is my castle".

And "home" is an adverb in

- I'm going home (where-to indication).
- I'm at home. - Here I would see "at home" as a two-part adverb indicating where. But you find it only in older texts.

This is exactly parallel to German "das Heim (noun), "Ich gehe heim"
(adverb, where to), "Ich bin daheim" (adverb, where).

In the meantime "at home" has been reduced to "home". When I learnt English
about 60 years ago "I'm home" would have been considered a mistake. Language is always changing.